# Find a table name in Xcode, Objective-C with Sqlite3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, compilation

I have to find a table name from a compiledStatement ( returned by `sqlite3_prepare_v2` method of sqlite3 library ).

I can't use the method `const char *sqlite3_column_table_name(sqlite3_stmt*,int);` because this methods requires the dylib compilded with the option `[SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA]`.

I want to know how to recompile the dylib with that option ( where i can find the code to compile and how to do that, with which command and flags? ) or if exists another method to fine the table name.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for kind of queries for which your statement is probably built, you can use this method,

```
/*
** CAPI3REF: Retrieving Statement SQL
**
** ^This interface can be used to retrieve a saved copy of the original
** SQL text used to create a [prepared statement] if that statement was
** compiled using either [sqlite3_prepare_v2()] or [sqlite3_prepare16_v2()].
*/
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_sql(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt);
```

to retrieve the Query used to build the statement. Once the query is obtained you can parse the query to get the table name.

For ex if your statement is an insert, You would get

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME...
```

now the third word is your table name. You can use ,

```
componentSeperatedByString
```

But I would prefer using Regular Expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
But I would avoid to search the name in to the query, because i want to make the code more general and reusable as possibile. 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Curlyman. If you find answer Please do post it.would be helpful!. Thanks.